# Viewing a particular html + django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to learn django by reading the tutorial and Django book on the net.

I am trying to display a web page on a url.

For the same I wrote in the url pattern function the statement `(r'^home/$' , home )` where I have imported the home function.

Also in the home function I wrote

```
def home( request ):

      return render_to_response("home.html",None) // home.html is placed in the templates folder along with its .css
```

This must be wrong as I don't intend to pass any response ... so please tell what i should write here...

However the issue I am facing is that when I go to the url the html comes in plain without the css styling without the color etc.....

When I check my html template however that is fine ...

So what do I need to do to display the html as it is in the url ???

Thanks..

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: You can give this link as an answer so I could accept it as this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the development server.
Make sure that your URLconf is correct:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

See: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development

Then your css files can be included like this:

```
{% load static %}
{% get_static_prefix as STATIC_PREFIX %}
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_PREFIX }}/yourpath/your.css" />
</head>
```

Off course the css files have to be located in your [static_media dir](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#using-django-contrib-staticfiles).

This means, as stated in the docs, that you should set `STATIC_ROOT` to the appropriate folder, for example a folder named 'static_media' in your project directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the .css in the STATIC_FILES directory (if you are using 1.3 or MEDIA_URL for 1.2)

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Then you need to link to the css in the head of the html file with something like:

```
<head>
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% get_static_prefix %}html.css" />
</head>
```